# PostgreSQL terminating connection due to administrator command

Tags: postgresql

After updating the application, I get the following errors from time to time and the database is inaccessible. Whenever I restart the database, then my applications are working again. Do I need to look at something on the server side? Or do I need to check the application side? **No one can access the server**. I m stuck in this situation.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
PostgreSQL Version: 9.6

```
2022-01-05 11:42:16.899 +03 [22668] db_5466@postgres ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uniq_number"
2022-01-05 11:42:16.899 +03 [22668] db_5466@postgres STATEMENT:  insert into TBL_HERE_ARE_LONG_QUERY
2022-01-05 11:42:16.916 +03 [22668] db_5466@postgres ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2022-01-05 12:46:41.660 +03 [30065] db_5466@postgres ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2022-01-05 12:46:41.660 +03 [30065] db_5466@postgres STATEMENT:  select table0_.Type as type_88_0__, table0_.counter as counter2_88_0_, table0_.SG as table3_88_0_, table0_.tsd as tsd4_88_0_ from TBL_TBL-001 table0_ where table0_.Type=$1 for update
2022-01-05 12:46:41.667 +03 [30067] db_5466@postgres ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2022-01-05 12:46:41.667 +03 [30067] db_5466@postgres STATEMENT:  select table0_.Type as type_88_0__, table0_.counter as counter2_88_0_, table0_.SG as table3_88_0_, table0_.tsd as tsd4_88_0_ from TBL_TBL-001 table0_ where table0_.Type=$1 for update
2022-01-05 12:46:41.674 +03 [30196] db_5466@postgres ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2022-01-05 12:46:41.674 +03 [30196] db_5466@postgres STATEMENT:  select table0_.Type as type_88_0__, table0_.counter as counter2_88_0_, table0_.SG as table3_88_0_, table0_.tsd as tsd4_88_0_ from TBL_TBL-001 table0_ where table0_.Type=$1 for update
2022-01-05 12:58:42.825 +03 [29800] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2022-01-05 12:58:42.825 +03 [29800] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-01-05 12:58:42.825 +03 [31711] postgres@postgres FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2022-01-05 12:58:42.825 +03 [30857] db_5466@postgres FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2022-01-05 12:58:42.825 +03 [30996] db_5466@postgres FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
```

Comment: Why are your log messages out of order by over 3 days?

Comment: More information needed: 1) Postgres version 2) OS and version 3) Can you log in with `psql`?. Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I have never tried login yet when I faced this issue. By the way, I did not want to copy whole logs. Because there are many sql queries. Is it clear @jjanes ?

Comment: When you say 'No one can access the server" do you mean the PostgreSQL server after it is shut down, or do you mean the Linux server in order to originate the shutdown?

Comment: If you provide non-contiguous blocks of log, you should separate them with '...' or something, and still show them in order.  Your first two lines (by position) don't seem relevant.  The last two lines do, but the lines immediately preceding them should be even more relevant.  Anything about receiving a smart shutdown request?

Comment: I updated the logs.

Comment: I mean "There is no manually shutdown the service" I just login the server myself.